# Getting error regarding --query in mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am getting an error while writing the mongoExport code in node.js

**Command:**

```
var quer_var= `'{"_id.userId":"${userId}","_id.type":"gapAnalysis","_id.timeStamp":"${timeStamp}"}'`
```

```
var command = `mongoexport --db ${process.env.DB_NAME} --collection preCaches --query ${quer_var} --type csv --fields MPN,L4Category,RevenueImpact --out ${process.env.DOWNLOAD_DIR_PATH+fileName}`
```

Error:

```
'{"_id.userId":"5fbf7fd344c67c48085383b1","_id.type":"gapAnalysis","_id.timeStamp":"2020-12-31T14:30:22+05:30"}'
2020-12-31T14:30:33.019+0530    query '[39 123 95 105 100 46 117 115 101 114 73 100 58 53 102 98 102 55 102 100 51 52 52 99 54 55 99 52 56 48 56 53 51 56 51 98 49 44 95 105 100 46 116 121 112 101 58 103 97 112 65 110 97 108 121 115 105 115 44 95 105 100 46 116 105 109 101 83 116 97 109 112 58 50 48 50 48 45 49 50 45 51 49 84 49 52 58 51 48 58 50 50 43 48 53 58 51 48 125 39]' 
is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
2020-12-31T14:30:33.022+0530    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: can you also share your JSON format

Comment: The query listed in that log output is `'{_id.userId:5fbf7fd344c67c48085383b1,_id.type:gapAnalysis,_id.timeStamp:2020-12-31T14:30:22+05:30}'` - is that how you intended the query to look?